# Existing view template not found

Tags: cakephp, view, render

CakePHP is giving me a mysterious error when trying to create a new view via $view = new View($this, false) on my server. The script runs perfectly on my local machine. On the server it says the view, that i want to render via this method wasn't found.

I have already tried chown/chmod. The file rights of all View files are all the same.

The URL to the guide which explains the concept is the following:
http://wp.headynation.com/cakephp-get-htmloutput-of-view-without-view-displaying-or-outputting-using-render/

Thank you

Comment: That looks like a bad piece of advice there. You should also show us some code. And more importantly: What are you trying to do there in the first place? Usually, you don't need to create a view yourself. PS: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: If you have win on local but linux server double check the file names, as linux is case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I have to use `$view->render('/Exports/_users.ctp');` instead of `$view->render('_users');`